# flash video streaming and embedding

Tags: flash, http-headers, video-streaming, http-streaming, video-embedding

Users upload different types of files (images, videos, audio, docs etc) on our DAM server and perform different operations on those. We have public links for all these assets to enable an access without any authentication.

We are having some problem working with flash videos uploaded on our server. Using a public link one can download and save the file alright. However when a public link is used in say a blog post, the video does not get displayed. When I try to open the same video using one of the desktop flash players it plays it fine when file is downloaded but fails to do so when pointed to a public link.

The embed code I use in a blog post is like this -

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="550" height="400" data="http://dam_server/flash/flashplayer.swf?file=url_encoded_public_url"> 
<param name="movie" value="http://dam_server/flash/flashplayer.swf?file=url_encoded_public_url" />
</object>
```

The relevant response headers from our server -

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
Connection: close
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="video.flv"
P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR CURa PSDa OUR NOR NAV STA"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1001503
Expires: -1
Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Sep 2011 08:29:01 GMT
ETag: "-1245634458"
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Probably we are setting some of the response headers with incorrect values.

The video plays alright within our system, but not in an independent page like a blog. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

p.s. I have checked many similar questions posted here but could not get required information.

Comment: Perhaps it can be a problem of cross domain calls. Have a look at crossdomain.xml files and how you can use them to allow access to your servers from other domains.

Comment: @Lars Blåsjö - Thanks for the reply. I tried that but probably that is not the problem. I added a crossdomain.xml file at the root of our server which didn't make any difference. The reason might be that the flash player as well as the flash file reside on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with cross domain calls. The only thing I had to do was set file-type for the flash player we are using. Our public links do not have an extension. So the flash player wasn't recognizing the file type unless the file-type was specified explicitly.